# Are code level changes required for moving to load-balancing environment?

Tags: coldfusion, load-balancing, coldfusion-10

My client wants to move to a ColdFusion load-balancing environment for better availability and scalability of the site. I know how to setup clusters and instances in the ColdFusion Admin. We should also use J2EE session mgmt for sticky sessions.

But I am not sure of other code level changes required while moving from a single server to load-balancing environment.

Anyone having any experience please suggest? Or any helpful links.

Comment: I agree with the the "official line" of why this was put on hold, but... it's a  bloody good question. And an aggregation of notes / suggestions on the topic must surely be a useful resource for people googling it later. Is that not the whole idea here? This smacks of a flaw in the way S/O considers what questions are meritorious or not.

Comment: Be careful about criticising the way things are being done.  It might be construed as volunteering to do it better.

Comment: No, it usually just results in being told "you don't understand Stack Overflow" in a patronising tone.

Comment: Are you talking about clustering on a single server or load balancing cross multiple servers?  These are not the same and offer different types of high availability effectiveness.

Comment: @DaveFerguson:Could you please explain the difference between the two. Moreover we are planning to set up single server clustering

Comment: Using a single server and running multiple CF engines for clustering will give you CF failure redundancy.  However, what if the server fails?  Clustering on a single server gives you no protection for that. Load balance first, then cluster if you have to.

Comment: In load balancing environment HTTPSession will either replicated to all Nodes or Distributed to some node of cluster....So all Object which are stored in HTTPSession Object must be serialized and try to minimize amount of the Object/Data which will store in HTTPSession Object......If there is any Object or Data stored in Cache instead of HTTPSession object than when Node crash or shutdown all Data/Object might be loss of cache......So you have to take care about cache replication or Distribution also......

Comment: @user3427540: Will this load balanced environment use CF scheduled tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Skipping the session scoped issues you're bound to enjoy I'll focus on less common code level strategies.

You will have 2+ isolated application scopes. This creates challenges in synchronicity. Examine the app code for writes to the app scope. Should some condition require updating an app scoped value, that value must be reflected in all sibling application scopes.

Know that each instance will have its own onApplicationStart() & onApplicationEnd() events. Depending on what happens in the code, it could cause mischief.

Be aware of things like FuseBox (framework) when load balancing. FuseBox generates files locally that are not replicated on other server instances.

When logging, emailing errors, etc., use an instance identifier so you'll know which server you're working with.

Should your app need the originating IP address of a request, you may need to enable X-Forwarded-For HTTP headers within your load balancer. Otherwise, you could get the IP of the load balancer on every request.

Verify Identical on EACH Instance:

- Security implementations
- ColdFusion & Java versions
- Datasources
- Mappings
- Virtual directories
- Shared resource locations ..
- CF Admin settings: site-wide error handling, etc.
- CF account privileges, Important!

Consider using the ColdFusion Server Manager to assist consistification. ;)